# ¿restar/sumar dos horas, lapso de tiempo de una hora a otra AM/PM php?

Tags: php

estoy sacando el lapso de una hora a otra, en excel tengo la siguien formula (24-h1+h2) esa formula me da el lapso de tiempo de una hora a otra.

ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado hacerlo con diff pero obtengo otro resultado ejemplo:

```
<?php

$fecha_ini = "04:00 PM";
$lote_fin = "06:40 AM";

$fecha1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $fecha_ini);
$fecha2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $lote_fin);
$interval = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
$tldias=$interval->format("%H, %i");

echo $tldias
```

resutado que obtengo es: 09, 20. cuando deberia ser 14:40, 14 horas y 40 minutos.

les agradeceria sus ayudas, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El resultado obtenido es correcto, si se tiene en cuenta que **es el tiempo transcurrido en el mismo día**

Para que de el resultado esperado, deberías analizar si `$fecha1` es mayor a `$fecha2`, y si es el caso, **sumarle un día a `$fecha2`**

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$fecha_ini = "04:00 pm";
$lote_fin = "06:40 am";

$fecha1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $fecha_ini);
$fecha2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $lote_fin);
if ($fecha1 > $fecha2) {
    $fecha2->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
$interval = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
$tldias=$interval->format("%H:%i");

echo $tldias;
// Resultado: 14:40
```

Comment: si, tienes razon, en realidad no sabia como sumarle las 24 horas, que es lo mismo que un dia.

Answer (score 1):

Para facilitar el calculo puedes incluir la fecha de referencia para ambas horas. En este caso la hora de fin es menor a la hora de inicio, deberia ser una fecha posterior.

El caso comun es que sea del dia posterior debido a que la hora es menor (en este caso basta con , pero puede darse el caso de que la hora de fin sea el dia siguiente a una hora posterior a la de inicio (mas de un dia, ej: hoy 4PM - mañana 6PM = 26 horas). Lo ideal es saber a que fecha corresponde cada hora y el calculo sera directo en cualquier caso.

```
<?php

$fecha_ini = "2020-09-04 04:00 PM";
$lote_fin = "2020-09-05 06:40 AM";

$fecha1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i A', $fecha_ini);
$fecha2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i A', $lote_fin);
$interval = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
$tldias=$interval->format("%H, %i");

echo $tldias
```

Ahora, si estas seguro de que la hora de fin no sera mas de 24 horas del inicio, bastaria con agregar un dia a la hora final si fuera menor a la hora de inicio.

Comment: gracias, por tu respuesta, pero sí la hora fin no es mayor a 24 horas por lo que en este caso, solo es necesario agregar, un dia, pero puede que alguien si necesite hacer la operacion teniendo en cuenta la fecha, por si hay más dias de diferencia.